# Using Laravel Homestead: 'no input file specified'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I am new to using Laravel, and Homestead, and would appreciate any help or a point in the right direction.  I have successfully been able to get to the "You have arrived" screen when I run "php artisan serve" but when I try to do the same thing via Vagrant, I get "no input file specified".  My Homestead.yaml file looks like this:

```
authorize: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/code/exampleproject
      to: /home/vagrant/code/exampleproject

sites:
    - map: exampleproject.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/exampleproject/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

On my computer I have the following directories:

```
/Users/me/code/Homestead
/Users/me/code/exampleproject //this is the directory created with composer
```

On my Vagrant Box I have for some reason two directories named "code" and "Code":

```
/home/vagrant/code/exampleproject 
/home/vagrant/Code
```

I have checked and I can see changes made to my computer exampleproject files are reflected in the vagrant box files.

Not really sure how to figure this out!!  I would really appreciate any help possible :)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Instead of reinstalling try

```
vagrant up --provision
```

or

```
homestead up --provision
```

Comment: `vagrant up --provision` didn't work for me, but `homestead up --provision` did

Comment: Just do `vagrant reload --proivision`.

Comment: This method is working also you can try vagrant destroy and vagrant up then i make all configurations and it much more cleaner.

Comment: hi i have the same problem here instead of homestead i run it in cpanel any suggestions?

Answer (score 45):

I had the same exact problem and found the solution through the use of larachat.

Here's how to fix it you need to have your homestead.yaml file settings correct. If you want to know how its done follow Jeffery Way tutorial on homestead 2.0 https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two.

Now to fix `Input not specified` issue you need to ssh into homestead box and type

`serve domain.app /home/vagrant/Code/path/to/public/directory` this will generate a serve script for nginx. You will need to do this everytime you switch projects.

He also discussed what I explained in this series https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Rudy!

Comment: I guess issue happens if add another project in Homestead right? Is it not possible to run `serve` automatically for all?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tutorial. Got it working now!

Comment: With a fresh install of vagrant, virtualbox, homestead... and trying destroy/up, the serve command is what finally worked. Thanks

Answer (score 31):

This is easy to fix, because you have changed the folder name to: **exampleproject**

So SSH to your vagrant:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Then change your nginx config:

sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/homestead.app

Edit **the correct URI** to the root on line 3 to this **with the new folder name**:

```
root "/Users/MYUSERNAME/Code/exampleproject/public";
```

Restart Nginx

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

**Reload the web browser, it should work now**

Comment: best answer in all the web for this problem. kudos!

Comment: This locked up my computer. Would be nice if the reasons for these commands were given - exactly why they are needed and what they are doing.

Answer (score 29):

For me the following worked:

`vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: This worked for me as well to get it to load the sites after I changed the base host directory to Code instead of webdesign. Thanks! – rhand just now   edit

Comment: It could be also a lowercase or uppercase problem in `Homestead.yaml` file. For example, I was mapping to `/phpmyadmin` when it my directory name it was actually `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: The reason I use this solution is it keeps my database data intact. This solution is described in more detail here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-proper-way-to-refresh-homestead-after-making-changes-to-the-homesteadyaml-file?page=0

Answer (score 8):

Giving my response just in case if anybody struggling with this issue.

1. You might need to verify that the server.root configuration in "/etc/ngnx/sites-available/domain" matching with your sites.to config in "Homestead.yaml".
2. If its not matching then change it and restart the webserver with "sudo service nginx restart"
3. And still things are not working then allow write permission for the "YOURSITE/app/storage" folder as "chmod -R 777 app/storage"

Answer (score 8):

I also had the same problem, I had assumed that Laravel is installed "out of the box" but it seems it isn't. I SSH'ed to the machine and ran these commands:

```
cd Code
sudo composer self-update #not necessary, but I did it anyways
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel --prefer-dist
```

And everything was running as usual.

Comment: Thanks Arda! That's the key. It took me a few hours :( You have to go inside the Virtual Machine and run: composer create-project laravel/laravel folder-name

Comment: What it's important to understand with the "No input file specified" error, is to look on your host machine the configuration of Homestead.yaml -> This file contains your sites mapping (map: homestead.test to: /home/vagrant/code/public ) This means that if you go to your virtual machine to root-> /home/vagrant/code/public/ you have to have your html php files there. If there are not there, run the: composer create-project laravel/laravel :) If everything works then you have to know that "~/" means "c:/windows/users/yourname/" so there will be your sincronized files from vagrant to your host

Comment: After hours of hair pulling, as someone new to Laravel, this was the key. I've had the most success by installing laravel first, and then adding per-project homestead to it afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issues

But forgot that the specs said the configuration file would be located at

~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml
and was updating 
~/Homestead/src/stubs/Homestead.yaml

So the FIX was to update the Homestead.yaml located here at

~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml

Before

`sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Laravel/public`

After

`sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/mysitename/public`

Then I ran
  `vagrant up --provision`

Hope this works for anyone else.

Answer (score 5):

This issue occurred for me after editing the Homestead.yaml. I resolved this issue by

```
homestead destroy
homestead up
```

Comment: sadly this works for me too, which resulst in my databases getting destroyed every time. Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: You might be able to just do 'homestead provision' instead. Also if you haven't already I'd recommend setting up seeders and migrations so you can be less protective of the database.

Comment: This fix my problem :D ,

and this is good : https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two

Answer (score 5):

Same issue for me.

Neither `vagrant provision` or `homestead up --provision` worked for me, but the below did - probably as homestead was already running when I modified the yml file

`vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 4):

I was just struggling with same situation. Following solved the issue:

If you have directory structure like this:

```
folders:
    - map: /Users/me/code/exampleproject
      to: /home/vagrant/code/exampleproject
```

Just create 'public' folder within exampleproject on your host machine.

Comment: That fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

After I renamed some directories, I had to destroy and rerun vagrant. None of the solutions here worked.

This worked for me:

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

Comment: Don't user vagrant destroy, Use vagrant halt to graceful shutdown your virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your homestead. Worked for me.

```
homestead destroy
homestead up
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while following the Laravel docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)

My problem was very simple, I missed read this part in the docs:

> Homestead.yaml file will be placed in the ~/.homestead hidden
>   directory:

So I was updating the wrong Homestead.yaml file, since the file was moved when I ran the bash init.sh command.

I only realised this after a lot of searching, so hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Windows 10 and has the following Homestead configuration

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    - map: ~/code               #folder in local computer where codes are stored eg, c:\xampp\htdocs\project1
      to: /home/vagrant/code    #folder in the VM where the above code will be mapped

sites:
    - map: homestead.local          #fake name of the site (redirect this domain to the above IP ie 192.168.10.10 in hosts file ie, c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts)
      to: /home/vagrant/code/public #complete path to index.php file in the local computer to be utilized by homestead.local 
databases:
    - homestead
```

I **PING**ed the homestead.local domain and was getting results.

But when I typed http://homestead.local in the browser, I got *'no input file specified'* error

I checked the code/public folder and there was no index file. I was sure the system was looking for the default file which was somehow missing.

Once I created an index file it started working fine.

**Update:**

Next time it happened after a change in the **Homestead.yaml** file, I ran `vagrant reload --provision` command and it worked.

It looks that running `vagrant reload` only will not provision the vagrant box. [Read here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/reload.html])

Answer (score 1):

Word of caution, linux is case sensitive.  That is probably why you see a "Code" and a "code" directory.

What I would do is redo the vagrant setup again and if you want to keep it simple and matching what the Homestead box has as a default make your directory in your host machine "Code" with uppercase.

You could also in the "folders" section just map to your "Code" folder in your machine, in case you decide to add more sites to your Homestead setup later.  That way under /home/vagrant/Code/ you will see all your site projects and you can ass more sites pointing to their "public" directories.

Comment: Thanks, @noeldiaz!  Yesterday, I ended up doing what you said.  I downloaded vagrant again, then removed my Homestead directory with "rm -r Homestead", then did vagrant up, and when I did I saw that the vagrant up procedure ran some additional things like booting up the nginx server.  When I tried the site it worked! Also, the "code" "Code" folder problem went away :)  I have done what you suggested as well, as far as the "folders" section.  I/m a little scared, since it seems I don't understand how to debug server/virtual box problem', but will continue on!  I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the nginx web server is **not** pointing to the right path.

There's two keys that you should look at: the `map` key under `folders` and the `to` key under `sites`. The `folders` key maps folders on your local machine to the vagrant VM. The `sites` key is used to create a virtual host on nginx with the value in `to`.

What you want to make sure is that `to` under `sites` points to the right path to `public`.

The problem was that I created my laravel project with `composer create laravel/laravel`. This created a folder in my current directory named `laravel`. Then without changing directories I installed the homestead helper with `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`.

After running `php vendor/bin/homestead make` and `vagrant up` my directory structure looked something like this:

```
$ cd laravel51
$ ls -a
.
..
.vagrant
laravel
composer.json
composer.lock
vendor
Homestead.yml
Vagrantfile
```

My Homestead.yml looked like this:

```
folders:
    - map: "/Users/USER/Sites/sandbox/php/laravel51"
      to: "/home/vagrant/laravel51"

sites:
    - map: laravel51
      to: "/home/vagrant/laravel51/public"
```

If you look closely, the `/Users/USER/Sites/sandbox/php/laravel51` path will be mounted onto the vagrant VM. This is the wrong directory because it should be pointing to the laravel project root where your app directory is. What happened here was that I was supposed to require the homestead helper while I was *in the project root*.

So now the question is what do I do? You've got two options: get rid of your current homestead VM and start over, but this time from the project root **OR** salvage what you have already.

If you want to salvage what you have, you'll have to move several files and a folder to your laravel project root.

These are the artifacts you'll need to move:

```
.vagrant
Homestead.yml
Vagrantfile
```

The `composer.json` won't be needed since you'll be requiring it later.

Move those files to your laravel project root and change your current working directory to there (`cd laravel`). At that point just update the `map` under `folders` and make sure that it's pointing to the project root. Also make sure that the `to` key under `sites` is the `to` key under `folders` with `/public` appended to it.

For example:

```
folders:
    - map: "/Users/USER/Sites/sandbox/php/laravel51/laravel"
      to: "/home/vagrant/laravel51"

sites:
    - map: laravel51
      to: "/home/vagrant/laravel51/public"
```

Now run `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` so that the homestead helper is required into your current project's composer.json file and installed.

Run `vagrant reload --provision` and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you edit the *Homestead.yaml* file.

If like me you tried `homestead up --provision` and didn't worked!
then try this (it works for me):

- `homestead destroy`
- `homestead up`

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of Homestead maps folders in `~/Code` to say for example by default `~/Code/laravel/public`. Notice the case capitalisations in `~/Code`. These are case sensitive. New versions use lower case `~/code`. Update these directories in your `Homestead.yaml` according to your actual directories.

**TL;DR;**

Update `~/Code` to `~/code` or vice versa depending on your actual directory names.

Answer (score 1):

I had such problem. I reviewed Homestead.yaml file and all files and all of the settings were correct. My problem removed after the following steps.

1-If you are in 
vagrant@homestead:~$
command line, type `exit` command.

2- Now you must be inside Homestead folder. run this command

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

3- run `vagrant ssh`

Now if you type the related address in your browser it should show the Laravel page.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 I had to ssh into my homestead server and run these commands:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

It's a file path problem so below are my folders & sites paths. Also, I had to use "vagrant destroy" as provisioning didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the config file of the domain:

the public folder of my project was created in /home/vagrant/Code/demo/public

the config file of the domain (for me /etc/nginx/sites-available/demo.app) had configured: "/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public" instead of "/home/vagrant/Code/demo/public".

Now it is working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with Homestead and just provisioning the box worked for me. So you should try this:

`vagrant provision`

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant provision` related codes didn't work for me, after lost some time, I've restart the whole system. Now it works... -,-"

Answer (score 0):

I edited `homestead.yaml` and `hosts` according to [this laracast tutorial](https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two) and restarted homestead using `vagrant suspend`, `vagrant halt`, etc. /`vagrant up`; I tried to `vagrant provision` as well, but `no file specified` only went away after I **restarted my computer** (I'm on Windows 7 PC) after doing all of the above. It is certainly a time consuming and tricky error.

This is what my working `homestead.yaml` looks like for ***two*** laravel projects:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
    - map: projectone.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/ProjectOne/public
    - map: projecttwo.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/ProjectTwo/public

databases:
    - laraveldb
```

and here is my `hosts` file:

```
...
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.10   projectone.app
192.168.10.10   projecttwo.app
```

Note, there are two separate installations of laravel in `D:\Projects\ProjectOne` and `D:\Projects\ProjectTwo`

I then access the first project by typing `projectone.app:8000` in the browser and `projecttwo.app:8000` for the second project.

P.S. I tested this for Laravel 5.2 on Windows

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you need to configure your nginx server properly in order to serve you application. You can do this following this guide, starting in the topic [Configure Nginx and the Web Root](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04).

After properly [configuring your symbolic link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3) between your /etc/nginx/sites-available and /etc/nginx/sites-enabled you need to make sure your root variable is set to your application's folder path. Set your nginx root from

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

to

```
/home/vagrant/Projects/ProjectOne/public
```

Also, you have to place index.php before your html files so php is served before html. Change this

```
index index.html index.htm;
```

to this

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

After finish your configuration restart your nginx server with

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Your application should be served now.

Answer (score 0):

**Try restarting your computer**

Had a working Homestead running locally, which at some point stopped and would get the "No input file specified" error. I couldn't trace it.

With a computer restart, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed the folder containing your Homestead project, you'll get this error. Visit your `Homestead.yaml` file and update any references to point to the renamed folder, then do `vagrant up` (etc.) again

Answer (score 0):

If your using a new version of larval 7 >= you can use from your homested directory `vagrant provision`

Answer (score 0):

This error only happens to me when I perform a new installation without creating the directories correctly, eg "correct": `C:\Users\userxyz\Code\public`.

Try removing the "public" directory, the error 'no input file specified' is displayed

**Homestead.yaml**

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
      #type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```