# No input file specified in URL on Laravel Homestead app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, vagrant

I believe I have everything set up exactly as it should be but consistently receive the following message when attempting to view my app in the browser.

Can anyone tell me where I may be going wrong?  I don't have anything set up in Oracle VM Virtualbox manager.  Could this be it?

My hosts file has

```
127.0.0.1       homestead.app
```

My browser is returning

[image]

**My project folder is set up as follows:**

[image]

**In my homestead.yaml, I 'think' my paths are correct**

[image]

**SSH into vagrant shows all files in projects/bookings folder**

[image]

Comment: I answered this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274387/using-laravel-homestead-no-input-file-specified/28837697#28837697

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I don't see bookings folder inside Code folder, my yaml file looks:

```
folders:
- map: C:\wamp\www\_homestead
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: xilo_black.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/xilo_black/public
```

and my local folder structure is

...www_homestead (here are my all files connected to vagrant and homestead and .vagrant folder)
...www_homestead\xilo_black (laravel files)

In code folder, there should be folders with apps
Code\bookings\public
Code\other_app\public

Comment: I have changed it to folders:
    - map: c:/Users/s13sb4/documents/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/projects/bookings/public but it still doesn't work

Comment: when you ls Code folder on VM, do you see bookings folder with laravel files inside?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to follow instructions on this link to ssh into vagrant machine and create a Laravel project there.

My sites in homestead.yaml then mapped to

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/bookings/public

http://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-no-input-file-specified-using-homestead

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the ip in the host file to the same ip you have in the homestead file

```
192.168.10.10       homestead.app
```