# Using Laravel Homestead: "no input file specified"

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm new to this so it's kinda have been taking me a while to set up, but following the official guide I still don't know where did I go wrong, my homestead.yaml looks like this

---

> ip: "192.168.10.10" memory: 2048 cpus: 2 provider: virtualbox
>
> authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
>
> keys:
>       - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> folders:
>       - map: C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects
>
> to: /home/vagrant/code
>
> sites:
>       - map: homestead.test
>
> to: /home/vagrant/code/public
>
> databases:
>       - homestead
>
> features:
>       - mariadb: false
>       - ohmyzsh: false
>       - webdriver: false

my host file looks like this:

> 192.168.10.10   homestead.test

but whenever I try to access http://homestead.test/ I get "no input file specified"
and I've tried most of the solutions online with entering vagrant reload --provision
and go through vagrant ssh and then create a new project using composer. Nothing worked for me.

I'd appreciate any additional guidance.

P.S.: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Laravel Homestead: 'no input file specified'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274387/using-laravel-homestead-no-input-file-specified)

Comment: yup, I tried most of the solutions suggested there but I'm not sure why it isn't working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `homestead.yaml` file, the spacing has to be 'spacebar' space, and spacing, indentation must be same as provide.

From the file alignment, clearly the spacing and indentation has ran off.

Comment: I didn't really edit the original file spacing, looks different here than the original file