# Why I got "No input file specified." message in my Homestead installation?

Tags: homestead

I have installed virtualbox  and  vagrant under my ubuntu 20

I created file /home/master/Homestead/Homestead.yaml with 2 hosts (I need mysql and mongodb):

```
ip: "192.168.56.56"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /_wwwroot/lar/MS/MS_Banners
      to: /home/vagrant/apps/MS_Banners


    - map: /_wwwroot/lar/MngProducts
      to: /home/vagrant/apps/MngProducts

sites:
    - map: local-ms-banners.test
      to: /_wwwroot/lar/MS/MS_Banners/public
      php: "8.0"


    - map: local-mng-products.test
      to: /_wwwroot/lar/MngProducts/public
      php: "8.1"

databases:
    - MS_Banners

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mongodb: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

services:
    - enabled:
          - "mysql"
```

Running command :

```
vagrant up --provision
```

I got long output with some red lines :

```
Bringing machine 'homestead' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '12.2.0' is up to date...
==> homestead: Running provisioner: file...
    homestead: /home/master/Homestead/aliases => /tmp/bash_aliases
==> homestead: Running provisioner: handle_aliases (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: setting authorize key (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: setting authorize permissions for id_rsa (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: mk_features (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: own_features (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: apt_update (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ign:1 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease
    homestead: Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x focal InRelease
    homestead: Hit:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release
    homestead: Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [57.7 kB]
    homestead: Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu focal InRelease
    homestead: Hit:7 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
    homestead: Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
    homestead: Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
    homestead: Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
    homestead: Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
    homestead: Hit:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
    homestead: Fetched 57.7 kB in 2s (29.4 kB/s)
    homestead: Reading package lists...
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Invalid feature: mysql
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Installing mongodb
    homestead: MongoDB already installed.
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: mariadb because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: postgresql because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: ohmyzsh because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    homestead: Ignoring feature: webdriver because it is set to false
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Installing php8.0
    homestead: PHP 8.0 already installed.
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Installing php8.1
    homestead: PHP 8.1 already installed.
==> homestead: Running provisioner: enable mysql (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
    // 2 LINES BELOW ARE RED
    homestead: Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
    homestead: Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql
==> homestead: Running provisioner: start mysql (shell)...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20221220-41221-1acw2t2.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20221220-41221-w2xeim.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Certificate: local-ms-banners.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Site: local-ms-banners.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20221220-41221-1aeuibw.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Certificate: local-mng-products.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Site: local-mng-products.test
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: inline script
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20221220-41221-23cr1x.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Checking for old Schedule
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Restarting Cron
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Restart Webserver
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating MySQL / MariaDB Database: MS_Banners
    homestead: We didn't find MariaDB ($mariadb), skipping $DB creation
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Creating Mongo Database: MS_Banners
    homestead: MongoDB shell version v4.4.18
    homestead: connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MS_Banners?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
    homestead: Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("305d08ae-ce7e-4439-a965-72163793dcfa") }
    homestead: MongoDB server version: 4.4.18
    homestead: WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Update Composer
    // THE LINE BELOW IS RED
    homestead: You are already using the latest available Composer version 2.5.0 (stable channel).
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20221220-41221-plsvhs.sh
==> homestead: Running provisioner: shell...
    homestead: Running: script: Update motd
==> homestead: Running provisioner: Run after.sh (shell)...
    homestead: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20221220-41221-1vqbufq.sh
```

But running both hostings in browser I got error message only :

```
No input file specified.
```

In my I added 2 lines at the end of file /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   master-at-home

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters


127.0.1.5   local-bi-currencies.com
...

192.168.56.56  local-mng-products.test
192.168.56.56   local-ms-banners.test
```

I have :

```
uname -a
Linux master-at-home 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 15:10:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ apt show  virtualbox
Package: virtualbox
Version: 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/misc
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Virtualbox Team <team+debian-virtualbox@tracker.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 112 MB
Depends: adduser, iproute2, procps, virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules, python3 (<< 3.9), python3 (>= 3.8~), python3.8, python3:any, libc6 (>= 2.29), libcurl3-gnutls (>= 7.16.2), libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.97), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libgl1, libgsoap-2.8.91, liblzf1 (>= 1.5), libopus0 (>= 1.1), libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1), libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2), libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libvncserver1 (>= 0.9.10), libvpx6 (>= 1.6.0), libx11-6, libxcursor1 (>> 1.1.2), libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxt6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.20.04.1), libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2), libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2), libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2), libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.0.2), libxcb1, libxext6
Suggests: vde2, virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
Conflicts: virtualbox-2.0, virtualbox-2.1, virtualbox-2.2, virtualbox-3.0, virtualbox-3.1, virtualbox-3.2, virtualbox-4.0, virtualbox-4.1, virtualbox-4.2, virtualbox-4.3, virtualbox-5.0, virtualbox-5.1, virtualbox-5.2, virtualbox-6.0, virtualbox-6.1
Homepage: https://www.virtualbox.org
Download-Size: 21.6 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Description: x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
 VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range
 of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on a
 Linux system.
 .
 This package provides the binaries for VirtualBox. Either the virtualbox-dkms
 or the virtualbox-source package is also required in order to compile the
 kernel modules needed for virtualbox. A graphical user interface for
 VirtualBox is provided by the package virtualbox-qt.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ apt show  vagrant
Package: vagrant
Version: 2.2.6+dfsg-2ubuntu3
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Ruby Team <pkg-ruby-extras-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 3,178 kB
Depends: libarchive-tools, curl, openssh-client, rsync, ruby, ruby-bcrypt-pbkdf (>= 1.0.0), ruby-childprocess (>= 0.6.0), ruby-ed25519 (>= 1.2.4), ruby-erubis (>= 2.7.0), ruby-i18n (>= 1.1.1), ruby-listen (>= 3.1.5), ruby-log4r (>= 1.1.9), ruby-net-scp (>= 1.2.0), ruby-net-sftp (>= 2.1), ruby-net-ssh (>= 5.1.0), ruby-rest-client (>= 1.6.0), ruby-vagrant-cloud (>= 2.0.3), ruby-zip (>= 1.2.2)
Recommends: vagrant-libvirt
Suggests: virtualbox (>= 4.0)
Breaks: virtualbox (>= 6.2)
Homepage: https://www.vagrantup.com
Ruby-Versions: all
Download-Size: 425 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Tool for building and distributing virtualized development environments
 This package provides the tools to create and configure lightweight,
 reproducible, and portable virtual environments.
 .
 Vagrant uses Oracle’s VirtualBox to create its virtual machines and then
 uses Chef or Puppet to provision them.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

What can be reason of this error? I do not see any config errors...

**UPDATED INFO:**
I found this
[Using Laravel Homestead: 'no input file specified'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274387/using-laravel-homestead-no-input-file-specified)
branch and try some hints from it :

1. I run all command as “master” (common) user, not root

   vagrant up --provision

But I still got error message :

```
No input file specified.
```

2. On command :

   homestead up --provision

I got

```
homestead: command not found
```

I found this
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/bash-homestead-command-not-found
branch

With advice to run command :

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

Not sure if I really neeed to run this command ?

I prefer to have Homestead installed globally, what I did with commands from docs at page https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/homestead
starting with command :

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
```

How this error can be fixed? Are there some additive logs, degugging options to find reason of this error ?

**UPDATED INFO # 2:**
I modified my /home/master/Homestead/Homestead.yaml file:

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

    - map: /_wwwroot/lar/MS/MS_Banners
      to: /home/vagrant/apps/MS_Banners


sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code

    - map: local-ms-banners.test
      to: /_wwwroot/lar/MS/MS_Banners/public
```

In the bash I can open root directory of my project :

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ cd apps
vagrant@homestead:~/apps$ cd  MS_Banners
vagrant@homestead:~/apps/MS_Banners$ ls -la
total 1236
...
```

and see all files of my project.

but running command :

```
vagrant up --provision
```

I can open php file under homestead.test url ok.
But with url local-ms-banners.test I still got “No input file specified.” error...

In my OS :

```
 echo $PATH;
/home/master/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/master/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/master/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/master/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

?

**UPDATED INFO # 3:**

At this subbranch

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274387/using-laravel-homestead-no-input-file-specified/29962065#29962065
I found a hint to use commands :

homestead destroy
homestead up

But trying to follow it I got unexpected results:

master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ homestead destroy

                                     
  Command "destroy" is not defined.  
                                     

master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ homestead -h
Description:
  List commands

Usage:
  list [options] [--] [<namespace>]

Arguments:
  namespace             The namespace name

Options:
      --raw             To output raw command list
      --format=FORMAT   The output format (txt, xml, json, or md) [default: "txt"]
      --short           To skip describing commands' arguments
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Help:
  The list command lists all commands:
  
    /home/master/.config/composer/vendor/bin/homestead list
  
  You can also display the commands for a specific namespace:
  
    /home/master/.config/composer/vendor/bin/homestead list test
  
  You can also output the information in other formats by using the --format option:
  
    /home/master/.config/composer/vendor/bin/homestead list --format=xml
  
  It's also possible to get raw list of commands (useful for embedding command runner):
  
    /home/master/.config/composer/vendor/bin/homestead list --raw
master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ homestead up --provision

                                
  Command "up" is not defined.  
                                

master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ homestead --provision

                                            
  The "--provision" option does not exist.  
                                            

list [--raw] [--format FORMAT] [--short] [--] [<namespace>]

master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ homestead provision

                                       
  Command "provision" is not defined.  

        
                       

master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ whereis homestead 
homestead: /home/master/.config/composer/vendor/bin/homestead

master@master-at-home:~/Homestead$ homestead -v
Laravel Homestead 13.3.2

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  completion            Dump the shell completion script
  help                  Display help for a command
  list                  List commands
  make                  Install Homestead into the current project
 wsl
  wsl:apply-features    Configure features in WSL from Homestead configuration
  wsl:create-databases  Create Databases in WSL from Homestead configuration
  wsl:create-sites      Create Sites in WSL from Homestead configuration
```

Have Laravel Homestead 13.3.2 different commands ?
Or do I have some invalid Homestead installed ?

I removed from folders “/apps” path

- map: /_wwwroot/lar/MS/MS_Banners
  to: /home/vagrant/apps/MS_Banners

with “code” subdirectory:

```
to: /home/vagrant/code/MS_Banners
```

and removed 2nd item :

```
to: /home/vagrant/apps/MngProducts
```

but when I enter box with command :

```
vagrant ssh
```

I still see directory “~/apps"
with 2 subdirectories “MngProducts” and “MS_Banners”
I have run commands

```
vagrant reload --provision
...
vagrant up --provision
```

many times, but looks like there were not applied.
What have I do to apply my config changes?

Thanks!

Comment: Plase look at UPDATED INFO # 2

Comment: and UPDATED INFO # 3